# Why does my setInterval run only once in react hooks?

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, setinterval

Why does this code only triggers the setInterval once and then stops...

```js
const MainBar = ()=> {

  const [clock, setClock] = useState("")

  useEffect(() => {
    const interval = setInterval(setClock(clockUpdate()), 1000);
    console.log('Im in useEffect', clock)
  });

...
```

Whereas passing it into another function makes it work each second like so ?

```js
const MainBar = ()=> {

  const [clock, setClock] = useState("")

  useEffect(() => {
    const interval = setInterval(()=>{setClock(clockUpdate())}, 1000);
    console.log('Im in useEffect', clock)
  });

...
```

Sorry I'm new to hooks and javascript.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`setInterval` requires a function to be passed for it to execute. It will execute the given function every second in this case. `() => { setClock(clockUpdate()) }` is actually an anonymous function; a function without a name. If you'd give it a proper name, it'd look like `function updater() { setClock(clockUpdate()); }`.

`setInterval(setClock(clockUpdate()), 1000)` doesn't work because `setClock(clockUpdate())` is already executed, even before it is passed to `setInterval`. It cannot schedule it to run again, because it's not a function, it is a result already.

Comment: Thanks but 
>setClock(clockUpdate()) is already executed
I still don't get the big picture, or full understanding of the concept, what further readings do you suggest I should do to fully understand how javascript works, please point me somewhere or guide me what my general approach towards learning javascript should be.

Comment: I don't have good references readily available, since I learned javascript over a long time myself. What I can recommend, is trying to learn separate things at a time. In the specific case of `setInterval()`, try to see what it does without react first. In the specific case of functions, try to use named functions first (`function abc() { }`), then move to `function() { ... }` and further to `() => { }` later on. Lastly, combine everything in a single application. The javascript ecosystem isn't easy, it really isn't :)

Answer (score 1):

You can try this by adding the second parameter in `useEffect` which means if the `clock` changes, `useEffect` will run again

```
useEffect(() => {
    const interval = setInterval(()=>{setClock(clockUpdate())}, 1000);
    console.log('Im in useEffect', clock)
  }, [clock]);
```